# Pandas.read_csv() with special characters (accents) in column names �

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, utf-8, special-characters

I have a `csv` file that contains some data with columns names:

- *"PERIODE"*
- *"IAS_brut"*
- *"IAS_lissé"*
- *"Incidence_Sentinelles"*

I have a problem with the third one ***"IAS_lissé"*** which is misinterpreted by `pd.read_csv()` method and returned as �.

What is that character?

Because it's generating a bug in my flask application, is there a way to read that column in an other way **without modifying the file?**

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.read_csv("Openhealth_S-Grippal.csv",delimiter=";").columns

Out[2]: Index([u'PERIODE', u'IAS_brut', u'IAS_liss�', u'Incidence_Sentinelles'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Looks like Pandas can't handle unicode characters in the column names. Try converting the column names to ascii. Note that you'll lose the accent.

Comment: The comment above is not true and wasn't true as of its posting - see any of the answers below for the proper way to handle non-ASCII (generally by setting encoding to utf-8 or latin1).

Answer (score 31):

I found the same problem with spanish, solved it with with "latin1" encoding:

```
import pandas as pd

 pd.read_csv("Openhealth_S-Grippal.csv",delimiter=";", encoding='latin1')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Latin1 encoding also works for German umlauts (utf8 did not). Gracias!

Comment: Worked! Thank you

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue with importing data for a Brazilian client!

Comment: Any other possible encoding? I just used it, but accents are displayed something like this: "Escandï¿½n"

Answer (score 13):

You can change the `encoding` parameter for read_csv, see the pandas doc [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#dealing-with-unicode-data). Also the python standard encodings are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

I believe for your example you can use the `utf-8` encoding (assuming that your language is French).

```
df = pd.read_csv("Openhealth_S-Grippal.csv", delimiter=";", encoding='utf-8')
```

---

Here's an example showing some sample output. All I did was make a csv file with one column, using the problem characters.

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Output:

```
    IAS_lissé
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Comment: Oups ! I got an error ( the same one ) `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: unexpected end of data`

Comment: That is because your data is not encoded to `utf-8`. Try `latin1`: `pd.read_csv("Openhealth_S-Grippal.csv", delimiter=";", encoding='latin1')`...

Comment: Yeah, `latin1` is what I had at first, but changed it to `utf-8`. @farhawa, if you want a better answer you can post your csv or a sample of it with the header so that we know what your encoding is.

Answer (score 13):

Try using:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: This ended up working for me. UTF-8 wasn't throwing an error - but it was turning "é" into "Ã©". latin1 didn't work - it threw an error on "ś".

Answer (score 4):

Using utf-8 didn't work for me. E.g. this piece of code:

```
    bla = pd.DataFrame(data = [1, 2])
    bla.to_csv('funkyNamé , things.csv')
    blabla = pd.read_csv('funkyNamé , things.csv', delimiter=";", encoding='utf-8')
    blabla
```

Ultimately returned: OSError: Initializing from file failed

I know you said you didn't want to modify the file. If you meant the file content vs the filename, I would rename the file to something without an accent, read the csv file under its new name, then reset the filename back to its original name.

```
    originalfilepath = r'C:\Users\myself\\funkyNamé , things.csv'
    originalfolder = r'C:\Users\myself'
    os.rename(originalfilepath, originalFolder+"\\tempName.csv")
    df = pd.read_csv(originalFolder+"\\tempName.csv", encoding='ISO-8859-1')
    os.rename(originalFolder+"\\tempName.csv", originalfilepath)
```

If you did mean "without modifying the file*name*, my apologies for not being helpful to you, and I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks..encoding 'ISO-8859-1' worked for me. My data had pound sign, semi colons etc.