# Python 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0

Tags: python, csv

```
import re

dictionary = dict()

for line in open('Group14.csv', encoding="utf8"):
    line = line.strip()

    date = re.findall('(\w+\s\w+\s\d+)\s\d+\S\d+\S\d+\s\S+\s(\d+)', line)
    tweet = re.findall(',(.*)', line)
    #print(date[0], tweet[0])
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if tweet[0] in dictionary.values():
            dictionary[date[0]] += 1
        else:
            dictionary[date[0]] = tweet[0]
print(dictionary)
```

I want to read data from one Group14.csv.
Remove extra white-spaces.
for the second column in Group14.csv i want to loop through it in order to run a cleaning condition which if true: will print that cell with adjacent coloumn 1 cell <>. If false: skip the line......

Then I want to output my cleaned data with both columns into another csv

**NOTE**: THE 1st COLUMN IS TWITTER DATE AND SECOND IS TWEET

Comment: TRACEBACK ERROR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clean.py", line 5, in <module>
    for line in open('Group14.csv', encoding="utf8"):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 621: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Python Version is 3.6.0

Comment: Your input file is likely to be in a non UTF8 encoding, probably latin1... `0xe0` is latin1 code for `à`

Answer (score 0):

As Serge Ballesta pointed out in the question comments:

> Your input file is likely to be in a non UTF8 encoding, probably latin1... 0xe0 is latin1 code for à

I had the same issue and that was it.

See the solution in this related SO question

[Pandas.read_csv() with special characters (accents) in column names �](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650407/pandas-read-csv-with-special-characters-accents-in-column-names)

In brief, you can define the encoding when reading the csv file. This should work:

```py
# ...everything before

for line in open('Group14.csv', encoding="latin1"): # change the encoding

# ...everything after
```