# Pandas.read_csv() - Data have special characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have file csv format that contains some data with special characters like Alejandro González Iñárritu. How to make the dataframe contain with special characters like this?

```
import pandas as pd
movies = pd.read_csv('tmdb-movies.csv', encoding= 'latin1')
movies['diretor'].loc[movies['id'] == 281957]
```

And the output is

```
5    Alejandro GonzÃ¡lez IÃ±Ã¡rritu 
Name: director, dtype: object
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please Post a Sample of Your Dataset along with your Expected Output

Comment: This link will help you. [link][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650407/pandas-read-csv-with-special-characters-accents-in-column-names

Comment: The output be like this Alejandro GonzÃ¡lez IÃ±Ã¡rritu, I expect that will be like Alejandro González Iñárritu

Comment: I try with the link but that be the same. There is step that I have to try before use that example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The type of distortion you see here is precisely what you would expect when a string has been encoded as utf-8 but read with some single-byte encoding, like latin-1. Are you *sure* that you have tried reading with `encoding='utf-8'`?

Comment: I've tried with change the encoding type to encoding= 'utf-8' as the suggestion many times but still give the same output. Or I have to do something to my csv file??

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure. Could you provide a sample dataset that is smaller than 7 Mbyte and which does not require registration to download? One line should be enough. Also, make sure the problem isn't on the *output* side — if you're outputting UTF-8 in a latin-1 environment, you get the same kind of distortion. So please provide a *complete* example, containing everything we need to reproduce the problem. And read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IpkWIMaWKULg1UkHPheh42iOYDTgifhQGUCPHD9pSV4/edit#gid=0) @TurePålsson

Comment: That's not a CSV file, it'a spreadsheet at Google Sheets. We need the actual CSV file that you are trying to read. (Having said that, if I download that Google sheet as CSV, I get what looks like a double-encoded file, i.e. a stream of characters that has been encoded as utf-8, decoded as some 8-bit encoding (possibly latin-1) and then encoded as utf-8 again. If that is indeed what your data looks like, it should preferably be fixed "upstream", whenever the file is created.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

`pd.read_csv("sample.csv",delimiter=";", encoding='latin1')`

`df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', encoding='utf-8')`

`df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Comment: I tried it but still the same

Comment: Provide sample data

Comment: I got the dataset from this link https://www.kaggle.com/siddheshshelke/tmdbmovierating-sample