# Saving to csv's to ADLS of Blog Store with Pandas via Databricks on Apache Spark produces inconsistent results

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I am connecting to resource via restful api with Databricks and saving the results to Azure ADLS with the following code:

```
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}


response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

token = response.json()['access_token']

payload={}
files={}
headers = {
  'Accept': 'text/csv',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +token}

for k in request_dic.keys():
  base_url = "https://feeds.myfeed.com/api/"
  url = base_url + request_dic[k]
  print(url)

  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

  dt = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), sep="|")

  dt.to_csv('/dbfs/mnt/holdingfolder/' + k)
```

Everything works fine, however an additional column is inserted at column A and the Column B contains the following characters before the name of the column like Ã¯Â»Â¿. , see image.

[image]

Is this something that is a quirk with Databricks?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the encoding parameter [**utf-8**](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) or `latin1`  for read csv ,

**Sample code:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("sample1.csv", delimiter=";", encoding='utf-8')
```

For more details, refer this [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650407/pandas-read-csv-with-special-characters-accents-in-column-names) thread by [shawnheide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3453737/shawnheide)

Comment: Hi Bhanunagasai, thanks for reaching out. I entered the following code ```dt = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), delimiter=";", encoding='utf-8')```
But I got the following error:
```arserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 4, saw 8```

Comment: hi @Patterson, try this code `encoding=utf-8-sig` and also check above SO thread it has detail information.

Comment: Hi, I tried the following at it didn't work at all ```dt = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), delimiter="|", encoding='utf-8-sig')```

Comment: I wonder if I can get some more help on this please

Comment: Just so you know the delimiter=";" won't work - I ge the error ```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 4, saw 8```

Comment: Please follow this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHCHKeJ6bI8&list=LL&index=1) it will solve your problem and explained in detail way.

Comment: ok, SO, I have virtually tried everything from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650407/pandas-read-csv-with-special-characters-accents-in-column-names but I still keep on getting the problem. Any thoughts greatly appreciated

Comment: ok, going to try the youtube you suggested. I really hope it works

Comment: BhanunagasaiVamsi-MT, thanks for your input but that vide didn't work at all. The problem appears to be work language. Don't know why you made me watch that YouTube?

Comment: I have just this minute tried ```dt = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text),sep="|", encoding='ISO-8859-1')``` but I getting the same incorrect output. Any more suggestions gladly welcomed

Comment: try this conversion `df['your_column_name'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')`

Comment: Hi, entered ```dt['Ã¯Â»Â¿COUNTRY ID'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')```,  but I got an Keyerror 'Ã¯Â»Â¿COUNTRY ID'